# apache camel RouteBuilder not work when passing header/param name from url

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl, servlet-3.0

i'm watching a camel example about Servlet, it works with this xml camel definition (camel-context.xml):

```
 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route id="helloRoute">
      <!-- incoming requests from the servlet is routed -->
      <from uri="servlet:hello"/>
      <choice>
        <when>
          <!-- is there a header with the key name? -->
          <header>name</header>
          <!-- yes so return back a message to the user -->
          <transform>
            <simple>Hi I am ${sysenv.HOSTNAME}. Hello ${header.name} how are you today? ****</simple>
          </transform>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
          <!-- if no name parameter then output a syntax to the user -->
          <transform>
            <constant>Add a name parameter to uri, eg ?name=foo</constant>
          </transform>
        </otherwise>
      </choice>
    </route>
```

It works with uri /hello and /hello?name=foo. I'm trying to replace xml dsl with Java dsl, like this (the camel context start one time when Servlet context start and stop when web application stop):

```
@WebListener
public class CamelRoutingInitializer implements ServletContextListener {

    DefaultCamelContext camctx;
    ServletContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ctx = sce.getServletContext();
        RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder() {
            /**
             *like camel-config.xml but with Java DSL syntax 
             * @see http://camel.apache.org/java-dsl.html
             */
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("servlet:camel")
                .choice()
                .when(header("name").isEqualTo("name"))
                .transform(body().append("Hi I am ${sysenv.HOSTNAME}. Hello ${header.name} how are you today? ****"))
                .otherwise()
                .transform(body().append("Add a name parameter to uri, eg ?name=yourname"));    
                ctx.log("** Route config ok");
            }
        };
        DefaultCamelContext camctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            camctx.addRoutes(builder);
            camctx.start();
            System.out.println("** CAMEL STARTED...");
            ctx.log("** CAMEL STARTED...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        if (camctx!=null && camctx.isStarted()){
            try {
                camctx.stop();
                ctx.log("** CAMEL STOPPED...");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

if uri is /camel i get "Add a name parameter to uri, eg ?name=yourname" but
the same thing happens using "/camel?name=foo" (instead of "Hi I am xxx Hello foo how are you today? ****")

What's wrong with it? webapplication uses both (camel-config.xml and  CamelRoutingInitializer class).

thanks

roby

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is on the line `header("name").isEqualTo("name")`. It is expecting that the value of the header be equal to the literal `"name"`. You should be simply stating `header("name")`, just like in the xml dsl.